# How to generate a new error report in Great Exceptions (data validation tools) or access the last one?

Tags: python, great-expectations

I recently became acquainted with **[Great Expectations](https://greatexpectations.io/)**, a *great* data validation library and was able to quickly create my own validation suite for a sample data source and view its output.
After creating a checkpoint and running it, only the overall success rate of the expectations was displayed on the command line, but I could not see the web report UI.
I noticed that when editing expectations, I can run the notebook again to see the report for the changes made, but I want to know if there is a faster way to do this or not.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the previously generated reports, I noticed that ‍***Great Expectations‍‍*** has a main web page for displaying validation reports, to which new reports are added each time a validation or checkpoint is executed.

***Just open this HTML file and click on the latest report.***

for me, this file was located at:

```sh
great_expectations\uncommitted\data_docs\local_site\index.html
```